Diblock building in Biovia material studio
I am trying to build polystyrene and polyethylenepropylene diblock chains.
When I assign head and tail and build diblock chain I could see that the atom numbers get flipped, meaning that head and tail sections need to be reassigned.
I am currently visualizing the data file of a single chain using Ovito and reassigning the head and tail sections to rebuild the diblock chains. Is there a better way of doing this?
